# Merge [process] and [processes]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I guess [processes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/processes) refers to multiple [process](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/process), but I don't see why [process](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/process) can't refer to both single / multiple processes so I don't think we really need [processes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/processes).

I think [processes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/processes) should be merged into [process](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/process).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems reasonable. I'd merge and synonymize.

---

```
updating post history, 62 rows affected
updating posts, 50 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 47 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [process] and [processes] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym processes -> process was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```